# Build list from dictionary values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary which have key value pairs like:

```
dict = {'a11': 1, 'a21': 0, 'a12': 1, 'a14': 2, 'a41': 1 . . . . . .. .  'a67':99, 'a23':98, 'a19':99}
```

all they key values are in form of a11, a12, a13 and so on and the values are from 0 to 99.

Now from the dict, I want to build the lists such that: 
list lst0 have keys which got values 0, 
lst1 have keys which got values 1 and so on .. 
lst 99 have keys which have values 99.

I am able to achieve the same when the values were less than 5 using the below code:

```
for key,value in d.items():
    if value==1:
        lst.append(key)
```

but how to achieve the result when we have more number of different values, say 100 or more and don't have to define all 100 lists explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `defaultdict`.

```py
from collections import defaultdict

container_dict = defaultdict(list)

for key, value in my_dict.items():
    container_dict[value].append(key)
```

The result is this, which you can access with the integer you want as key:

```py
>>> container_dict
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {1: ['a11', 'a12', 'a41'], 0: ['a21'], 2: ['a14'], 99: ['a67', 'a19'], 98: ['a23']})

>>> container_dict[1]
['a11', 'a12', 'a41']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dct = {'a11': 1, 'a21': 0, 'a12': 1, 'a14': 2, 'a41': 1 , 'a67':99, 'a23':98, 'a19':99}
lists_of_keys = [[k for k,v in dct.items() if v == val] for val in set(dct.values())]
print(lists_of_keys)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
# Assume
mydict = {'a11': 1, 'a21': 0, 'a12': 1, 'a14': 2, 'a41': 1, 'a67':99, 'a23':99}

# unique values are:
uniques = list(set(mydict.values()))
# uniques = [1,0,2,99]

# for each unique value filter the keys those have that unique value. 
result = {f'lst{m}':[y[0] for y in filter(lambda x:x[1]==m, dict.items())] for m in uniques}

# {
#   'lst0': ['a21'],
#   'lst1': ['a11', 'a12'],
#   'lst2': ['a14', 'a41'],
#   'lst99': ['a67', 'a23']
#}
```